# Which locale will apply to cout after cout.rdbuf(fout.rdbuf())?

Tags: c++, unicode, internationalization, locale, iostream

```
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream fout("test.txt");

    fout.imbue(locale("chs"));
    cout.imbue(locale("C"));

    cout.rdbuf(fout.rdbuf());
    cout << "中文"; // Which locale will apply to here? "C" or "chs"?
}
```

The question is commented in the code.

Comment: heh, I've read your nick as "xilinx" :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/imbue/

> `std::ios::imbue <ios>`
>
> `locale imbue ( const locale& loc );`
>
> **Imbue locale**
>
> Associates loc to both the stream and its associated stream buffer (if
>   any) as the new locale object to be used with locale-sensitive
>   operations.
>
> All callback functions registered with register_callback with
>   imbue_event as its first parameter are called.
>
> In fact, this member function calls its inherited homonym
>   ios_base::imbue(loc), and if the stream is associated with a stream
>   buffer, **also calls rdbuf()->pubimbue(loc).**

Also, see http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/27-4.html

> **27.4.4 Collaboration of Locales and Iostreams**
>
> The base class ios_base contains a locale object. **The formatting and
>   parsing functions defined by the derived stream classes use the
>   numeric facets of that locale.**
>
> The class template basic_ios holds a pointer to the stream buffer.
>   This stream buffer has a locale object, too, usually a copy of the
>   same locale object used by the functions of the stream classes. **The
>   stream buffer's input and output functions use the code conversion
>   facet of the attached locale.**

In your case, it would use the "C" numeric locale and the "chs" character locale.